# Opengl texture flickering in some android devices

Tags: android, mobile, opengl-es, 3d, tablet

We are a team of developers working on a terrain visualization software over a virtual 3D globe. The project is aimed at mobile devices running android, mainly tablets and mobile phones. We have tested this in several devices and, while mobile phones seem to run the application fine (we haven't detected any issues on any of them), some tablets seem to have problems when drawing the textures in the screen.

For clarity purposes, im attaching a video that displays the problem, since its a little difficult to explain with words. This example shows a sphere divided in 200 sectors, each one with a different texture.

[Texture problem video](http://vimeo.com/36541512)

As you can see, sometimes it looks like it is trying to draw two different textures in the same sector at the same time.

We have tested this in these devices:

- Samsung Galaxy S SLC (ok)
- HTC Desire (ok)
- Nook Ebook Reader (ok)
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (doesnt work propperly)
- Sony Tablet S (doesnt work either)
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0 (ok)

Im posting the critical code that may be involved in this. First the fragment shader that is used to draw the textures:

```
varying mediump vec2 TextureCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Sampler;
....
gl_FragColor = texture2D (Sampler, TextureCoordOut);
```

Next, im posting the key instructions that are executed in OpenGL, since the code is spared in several big functions:

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(num, idTextures, 1);  //declare 200 textures
...
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, idTextures[texture]); //texture binding
...
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(Attributes.Position, size, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride, fb);
...
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(Attributes.TextureCoord, size, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride, fb);
...
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first, count);
```

Im sorry not to be able to provide more details, but after several weeks of debugging, we have no clue at all of what could be causing this. Im turning to you hoping for any leads, since we are completely lost right now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding ``glFlush`` or ``glFinish`` after every rendering cycle might help a bit as you seem to be doing rather extensive rendering state changes constantly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didin't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think I might know what causes you difficulties. The only devices where it doesn't work for you are Tegra 2 devices. I recently started working with a Tegra 2 device and noticed certain differences. Compared to other devices Nvidia seems to have introduced certain kinds of rounding errors where some things can behave differently from other GPUs. I had to go to extreme lengths and use workarounds to get it working the way I want with my complex shaders.

And what I could see on your video looks sort of like the z-buffer might not have enough resolution and that causes some kind of z-fighting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting. I am not sure because I don't really see from your code/description if you are drawing triangles that are very close together and can cause this kind of behaviour in the z-buffer.

But maybe you can try to scale the vertices (x,y,z) somewhat up or down and see what happens to the flickering. If it changes it probably has something to do with that, if not, the problem might have another reason, but then a little more code would be nice.

It would also be interesting to try to narrow it down by not painting the whole sphere but just one or two triangles where the problem occurs and see if it still happens.

PS: A longer video would have been better, short clips suck on vimeo.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I havent been able to check anything yet but some of the info you have provided looks promising! I will give you some feedback as soon as I can. Also, Ill try to post some more detailed code (as I said its hard cause the code is quite big) and longer videos.

Comment: Ok I have done some tests. There is no problem with z-buffer in this case. We have removed the back side of the sphere, and only sectors from 0 to 80 are being displayed. This means that most of colored pixels have an only triangle projected on it, so there is no z-buffer fighting. Every sector is composed of 16x16 vertices (256 triangles), and no overlapping between them.

Yes, it must be some problem related to Tegra2, but we still don't know what it is.

Comment: Things that might be worth investigation: Is the flickering only on certain triangles/squares or does it happen on all of them ? Does it happen if you change the texturing (only use 1 texture for all) ? Can you change opengl to 1.1 for testing purposes or does it have to be 2.0 ? How much texture memory do you use ? There are many things you haven't posted about what you are actually doing so anything I can say is unfortunately just pure speculation. I would really recommend you just display one triangle and see what happens and then slowly increase that number.

Comment: Ok after a few tests it *seems* that using glDrawArrays was causing this issue. We have changed it for glDrawElements and everything works fine now. Maybe a bug in glDrawArrays for tegra2? Anyway thanks a lot for the help.